# to use a resource pool of forklifts for different process flows and different tasks to the same time

Tags: anylogic

Is it possible to use a resource pool with forklifts for different process flows? I would like to  have a resource pool of 100 forklifts which I use for different tasks to the same time. So for example forklift 1 should transport pallets at 6 am to pallet rack 1 and forklift nr2 should transport pallets at 6 am to pallet rack 2. So currently I have a lot of resource pools for different tasks and I would like to know if it is also possible with only one resource pool.

Comment: NB: Felipe's answer assumes you want to *selectively* use resources from a single resource pool in different places. If you just want a single resource pool to be shared by blocks in different process flows then that happens by default; a resource pool is conceptually a pool of resources that is 'shared' by all blocks which seize/release from it, whatever 'flow' they are part of (e.g., Seize, Release, Service, RackStore). Did you not try in a simple model first before posting? If not, what was the understanding barrier preventing you doing so?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible... on the seize or service block, on the advanced section of the properties you can check the box "customize resource choice" and you will be able to select the resource you want to use for each one of the tasks.

Your resources will need at least an id, so you can do ((YourResourceType)unit).id==2 for example as the resource condition for your resource to be used for what you want. This condition you will see it as soon as you check the "customize resource choice" box.